# iOS9で新しくなった「メモ」アプリの手書きラインは どのような技術でできているのでしょうか？

Tags: swift

iOS9で新しくなった「メモ」アプリの手書きラインは
どのような技術でできているのでしょうか？

かすれた線などがとても素早くかけます。

このようなものを実現するための
フレームワークなどありますでしょうか？

CoreGraphicsや
SpriteKitで同様のことは可能でしょうか？

SpriteKitで

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            //点を描く
            let r = CGFloat(3.0)
            let dot = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: r)
            dot.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

            addChild(dot)

            dot.position = location

        }
    }
}
```

として試しましたが、
素早く描くと、図形が飛び飛びに描かれて、
線状には全くなりません。（下図）

[image: 図]

OpenGLなどを使わなければ、
素早さに対応できないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 反応速度が速いわけではなく、点と点の間を後から線でつなげているだけだと思います。「スプライン曲線」などで調べてみてください。